# how can mongodb push a value into the specified array subscript

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

1. my environment was mongodb 2.6.4

I need to insert an array into the specified array subscript.
I tried it.

I need push a first array first , then insert an array into the specified array subscript.

```
db.a.update({_id:1},{$push:{'list':[1]}},upsert=true)
db.a.update({_id:1},{$push:{'list.2':2}},upsert=true)
```

I used the following a statement is incorrect.

```
db.a.update({_id:1},{$push:{'list.2':2}},upsert=true)
```

I want a statement to achieve it. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [$position](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator in mongo. The index of $position starts from 0 so you should be careful with index. The query will be like following:

```
db.collection.find({_id:1},{$push:{list:{$each:[2],$position:1}}})
```

Comment: How to insert a value into greater than the length of the array  position, the middle position is filled with null.

Comment: @FankZhou What do you want here? Answer push element in specified position. If you are trying to insert elements in array greater than the length of the array position then only intermediate elements will be 'null'.

Comment: Insert a value into the array of the specified location, the array is automatically expanded to its specified size, there is the query that it?

Comment: sorry my english was so poor.   your's example was only put values into the last one.  I want to push element in specified position.

Comment: @FankZhou If you want to add element at the last of list then you can simply use `$push` without any index.